# Yognidra and getting slept while doing Yognidra

Tags: sleep, yog-nidra

Lot of Gurus ask to not falling into sleep while doing [Yognidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_nidra).

Lot of others Gurus ask to do [Yognidra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_nidra) for falling into sleep.

Which is right? Should be try to stay awake or we should sleep while doing Yognidra?

Comment: You already asked a very similar question, try to combine them if possible

Comment: @mar: All those questions are very diffrent to each other. Even if they are similar and if I will combine multiple related questions then someone will mark that question too broad. And will mark for close.